# @PostConstruct doesn't work with class loading parent last on WAS 8.5

Tags: java, cdi, resteasy, websphere-8

I'm using WebSphere 8.5 with class loading option parent last. In my ApplicationScoped bean there is @PostConstruct method which is not invoked in any case. When I'm changing to parent first all works fine, but I have issue with resteasy: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org/jboss/resteasy/specimpl/BuiltResponse.getHeaders()Ljavax/ws/rs/core/MultivaluedMap (that's why I'm isung parent last option). Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Do you have any error or warning showing up while starting the project?

Comment: @sgpalit no, I don't. Moreover, injection works fine